# C code runs in Eclipse-Kepler but fails to run in Codeblocks IDE

Tags: c, eclipse, gcc, codeblocks

I am a newbie at C programming and new on Stackoverflow as well.

I have some c code that compiles and runs in Eclipse Kepler (Java EE IDE); I installed the C/C++ plugin and Cygwin Gcc compiler for c. 
Everything runs ok in Eclipse IDE; however, when my friend tries to run the same code on his Codeblocks IDE, he doesn't get any output. At some point, he got some segmentation error, which we later learned was due to our program accessing memory space that didn't belong to our program.

Codeblocks IDE is using Gcc compiler not cygwin gcc, but I don't think they're that different to cause this sort of problem.

I am aware that C is extremely primitive and non-standardized, but why would my code run in eclipse with cygwin-gcc compiler but not run in Codeblocks IDE with gcc compiler?

Please help, it's important for our class project.

Thanks to all.

[EDIT] Our code is a little large to paste in here but here's a sample code of what would RUN SUCCESSFULLY in eclipse but FAIL in codeblocks, try it yourself if you have codeblocks please:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(void) {
    char *traceEntry1;
    FILE *ifp;

    traceEntry1 = malloc(200*sizeof(char));
    ifp = fopen("./program.txt", "r");

    while (fgets(traceEntry1, 75, ifp)) 
      printf("String input is %s \n", traceEntry1);
    fclose(ifp);
}
```

It simply doesn't give any outputs in codeblocks, sometimes just results in a segmentation fault error.

I have no idea what the problem is.

We need your help please, thanks in advance.

Comment: If your code includes errors which result in undefined behaviour, it may appear to work in some environments and fail in others.  You'll need to post code for more detailed feedback.

Comment: "I am aware that C is extremely primitive and non-standardized" C is extremely well standardized. The problem is that unless you're familiar with the standard, it's very easy to find yourself in non-standard land. And, considering the expressive capabilities of C relative to even lower level languages and how well it's managed to run the world for the past 40 years, I don't think it's quite fair to call it primitive :).

Comment: @Corbin, I'm sorry if I upset you. I meant to say "primitive" relative to other languages like Java, which is (1) Portable from one machine to another with no added effort which C doesn't have; and (2) and whole library of functions packaged to help you be more productive. C is indeed closer to the machine and thus faster by prob a few milliseconds but it's unforgiving with compiler and run-time error support. That being said, C is indeed a very powerful tool to the one who's mastered it but such a learning curve to the newbie, which I am and thus doing these projects in C so I can get better.

Comment: Try adding "printf("%s\n", strerror(errno));" just after you call ifp. You will need to include <errno.h>. (Also, you should always check whether fopen returns NULL). You could also use getcwd to make sure that your program is being run in the right directory.

Comment: Thanks Noshenim, I tried that but still nothing. Any other ideas? Were you successful in running that piece of code in your codeblocks? You gave me a better idea to debug this program though, thank you.

Comment: If you tried what *noshenim* proposed: Did `malloc()` or `fopen()` return `NULL`? If yes, what was the value of `errno`?

Comment: I bet `fopen()` returns `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

Always and ever test the results of all (revelant) calls. "relevant" at least are those call which return results which are **unusable** if the call failed.

In the case of the OP's code they are:

- `malloc()`
- `fopen()`
- `fclose()`

A save version of the OP's code could look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) 
{
  int result = EXIT_SUCCESS; /* Be optimistic. */
  char * traceEntry1 = NULL; /* Always initialise your variables, you might remove this during the optimisation phase later (if ever) */
  FILE * ifp = NULL;   /* Always initialise your variables, you might remove this during the optimisation phase later (if ever) */

  traceEntry1 = malloc(200 * sizeof(*traceEntry1)); /* sizeof(char) is always 1. 
              Using the dereferenced target (traceEntry1) on the other hand makes this 
              line of code robust against modifications of the target's type declaration. */ 
  if (NULL == traceEntry1)
  {
    perror("malloc() failed"); /* Log error. Never ignore useful and even free informaton. */
    result = EXIT_FAILURE;  /* Flag error and ... */
    goto lblExit;  /* ... leave via the one and only exit point. */
  }

  ifp = fopen("./program.txt", "r");
  if (NULL == ifp)
  {
    perror("fopen() failed"); /* Log error. Never ignore useful and even free informaton. */
    result = EXIT_FAILURE; /* Flag error ... */
    goto lblExit;  /* ... and leave via the one and only exit point. */
  }

  while (fgets(traceEntry1, 75, ifp)) /* Why 75? Why not 200 * sizeof(*traceEntry1) 
                                         as that's what was allocated to traceEntr1? */
  {
    printf("String input is %s \n", traceEntry1);
  }

  if (EOF == fclose(ifp))
  {
    perror("fclose() failed");
    /* Be tolerant as no poisened results are returned. So do not flag error. It's logged however. */
  }

lblExit: /* Only have one exit point. So there is no need to code the clean-up twice. */

  free(traceEntry1); /* Always clean up, free what you allocated. */

  return result; /* Return the outcome of this exercise. */
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much alk, I will test this out and thumb you right up if it works since other people with similar problems will be coming here. But thanks again so much for this very elaborate and much more helpful answer. I should get back to you before midnight today, thanks.